# Using OkHttp3 WebSocket with Retrofit to continuously track an android devices location

Tags: java, android, websocket, retrofit2, okhttp

I have the following java code that I'd like to use in an android app to query an api for continuous lat/lng changes of a device that is running a client app, I want to track the device.  I believe the WebSocketCall method I'm attempting to use is deprecated.  From what I can tell, there's a problem with how I'm trying to use the webSocket call to create the retrofit client and enqueue the data from the WebSocketListner into retrofit. I've researched several WebSocketListener examples and being a total n00b, I haven't been able to figure out the code.  My idea is to keep the connection open to the api via WebSocket and process the data response using retrofit. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
private WebSocketCall webSocket;

    private void createWebSocket() {
        final MainApplication application = (MainApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
        application.getServiceAsync(new MainApplication.GetServiceCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady(final OkHttpClient client, final Retrofit retrofit, WebService service) {
                User user = application.getUser();
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(user.getLatitude(), user.getLongitude()), user.getZoom()));
                service.getDevices().enqueue(new WebServiceCallback<List<Device>>(getContext()) {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(retrofit2.Response<List<Device>> response) {
                        for (Device device : response.body()) {
                            if (device != null) {
                                devices.put(device.getId(), device);
                            }
                        }

                        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(retrofit.baseUrl().url().toString() + "api/socket").build();
                        webSocket = WebSocketCall.create(client, request);
                        webSocket.enqueue(new WebSocketListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(IOException e, Response response) {
                                reconnectWebSocket();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onMessage(ResponseBody message) throws IOException {
                                final String data = message.string();
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            handleMessage(data);
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            Log.w(MainFragment.class.getSimpleName(), e);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                                reconnectWebSocket();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFailure() {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why you not trying to use `OkHttpClient.newWebSocket`?

Answer (score 1):

So because I'm a total n00b it took some time and a lot of questions to figure this out.  Maybe it'll help someone else in the future.

```
 private WebSocket webSocket;

private void createWebSocket() {
        final MainApplication application = (MainApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
        application.getServiceAsync(new MainApplication.GetServiceCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady(final OkHttpClient client, final Retrofit retrofit, WebService service) {
                User user = application.getUser();
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(user.getLatitude(), user.getLongitude()), user.getZoom()));

                service.getDevices().enqueue(new WebServiceCallback<List<Device>>(getContext()) {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(retrofit2.Response<List<Device>> response) {
                        for (Device device : response.body()) {
                            if (device != null) {
                                devices.put(device.getId(), device);
                            }
                        }

                        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(retrofit.baseUrl().url().toString() + "api/socket").build();
                        Log.e("WebSockets", "Headers: " + request.headers().toString());
                        WebSocketListener webSocketListener = new WebSocketListener() {
                            private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
                            @Override
                            public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
                                webSocket.send("{Auth-Token:secret-api-token-here}");
                                Log.e("WebSockets", "Connection accepted!");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull Throwable t, @Nullable Response response) {
                                reconnectWebSocket();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onMessage(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull String text) {
                                final String data = text;
                                Log.e("WebSockets", "Receiving : " + text);
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            handleMessage(data);
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            Log.w(MainFragment.class.getSimpleName(), e);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
                                Log.e("WebSockets", "Receiving bytes : " + bytes.hex());
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
                                webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
                                Log.e("WebSockets", "Closing : " + code + " / " + reason);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onClosed(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NotNull String reason) {
                                reconnectWebSocket();
                            }
                        };

                        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, webSocketListener);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFailure() {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```